# python: find html tags and replace their attributes

Tags: python, html, parsing, tags

I need to do the following:

1. take html document
2. find every occurrence of 'img' tag
3. take their 'src' attribute
4. pass founded url to processing
5. change the 'src' attribute to the new one
6. do all this stuff with Python 2.7

P.S. I,ve heard about lmxl and BeautifulSoup. How do you recommend to solve this problem with? Maybe it would be better to use regexes then? or another something else?

Answer (score 7):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string)
for link in soup.findAll('a')
    link['src'] = 'New src'
html_string = str(soup)
```

I don't particularly like BeautifulSoup but it does the job for you. Try to not over-do your solution if you don't have to, this being one of the simpler things you can do to solve a general issue.

That said, building for the future is equally important but all your 6 requirements can be put down into one, *"I want to change 'src' or all links to X"*

Answer (score 6):

Using [lxml](http://lxml.de/),

```
import lxml.html as LH
root = LH.fromstring(html_string)
for el in root.iter('img'):
    el.attrib['src'] = 'new src'
print(LH.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
```

Parsing HTML with regex [is generally a bad idea](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).
Using an HTML parser like BeautifulSoup or lxml.html is a better idea.

One attraction of using BeautifulSoup is that it has a familiar Python interface. There are lots of functions for navigation: `find_all`, `find_next`, `find_previous`, `find_parent`, `find_next_siblings`, etc.

Another point in favor of BeautifulSoup is that sometimes BeautifulSoup can parse broken HTML (by inserting missing closing tags, for example) when `lxml` can not. `lxml` is more strict and simply raises an exception if the HTML is malformed.

In contrast to the multitude of functions provided by the BeautifulSoup API, `lxml` mainly uses the XPath mini-language for navigation. Navigation using XPath tends to be more succinct than the equivalent using BeautifulSoup. The problem is you have to [learn XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp). [lxml is also much much faster than BeautifulSoup.](http://www.crummy.com/2012/01/22/0)

So if you are just starting out, BeautifulSoup may be easier to use instantly, but in the end I believe lxml is more pleasant to work with.

Comment: if you will need the text position of the tag, can you use a parser?

Comment: The parser *per se* will not give you this information because (from the parser's point of view) only the DOM should be important. You might be asking an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) since the general concensus on stackoverflow seems to be that you shouldn't be needing this information either :).

Answer (score 3):

Just throwing this answer in there, if you wanted to use regexes:

```
html = """
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
"""

import re

find = re.compile(r'src="[^"]*"')

print find.sub('src="changed"', html)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `lxml` approach:

```
import lxml.html

filename = 'your_html_filename.html'
document = lxml.html.parse(filename)
tag = 'your_tag_name'
elements = document.xpath('//{}'.format(tag))

for e in elements:
    e.attrib['src'] = 'new value'

result = str(document)
```

For your particular problem there is no precise advantage in using `BS` or `lxml`. This will matter only in the context of your problem.