# Mapping hyperlink name to address

Tags: python, html, hyperlink

I am trying to write python code to extract links from a web page. As per logic, I am looking
for the sequence `<a href="">.` The code extracts the link address from a normal anchor tag like -
`<a href="https://www.google.com"`, but I see that there are other ways of specifying hyperlinks
as under -

```
 <a href="/news/">News</a>
 <a href="/docs/">Documentation</a>
 <a href="/downloads/">Downloads</a>
 <a href="/support/">Support</a>
```

On clicking '/news/' the address that it resolves to is "https://www.reviewboard.org/news/".
How does this happen, and where is this information stored ?
Because '/news/' is useless by itself unless converted to complete string
https://www.reviewboard.org/news/.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python: find html tags and replace their attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357506/python-find-html-tags-and-replace-their-attributes)

Comment: Not exactly. Its using an existing attribute from the given tag, whereas I need to map a href string to its complete link address which is not present there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are relative links. It's the link *relative* to the page where the link is found.

So if I am on `www.somewebsite.com/somepage`, and I encounter this link:

```
 <a href="/someotherpage/">Some other page</a>
```

It will take me to `www.somewebsite.com/somepage/someotherpage`

These work the same way a relative path works, including `../` syntax to point back up through the file structure.

Comment: Is this also a relative link - <a href="//myactivity.google.com/product/search?utm_source=google&amp;hl=en-IN&amp;fg=1" role="menuitem">History</a> ?
It expands to https://myactivity.google.com/privacyadvisor/search?utm_source=googlemenu&fg=1
I guess, that its a specific https use case.